# How to find rectangular areas in a two-dimensional array whose distance from the center of the rectangle is less than the specified value of x

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray, euclidean-distance

I'm looking for rectangular areas in a non-negative two-dimensional float array in numpy where the distance to the center point of the area is less than x. In fact, the purpose of data analysis is the output of a depth estimation function in which I specify the areas that are less distant from each other (which can be said, for example, to be part of a wall or objects that are vertical and facing the camera).

For example, in the image below, the output of the depth estimation function can be seen, where each pixel represents a distance between 0 and 500 cm. In any area where the difference in size is less than a value indicates that the object is in a vertical position and I am looking for these areas

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z2Bsi5ZNoo4pFU6N188leq56vGHFfvcd/view?usp=sharing

The code I am working on is related to MiDas, at the end of which I have added my code, which is in the following link

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1vsfukFqOOZZjTajySM8hL0VNCvOxaa6X?usp=sharing

Now, for example, I'm looking for areas like this paper that are stuck behind a chair in the picture below

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ui99gpU2i0JFumLivLpoEyHn3QTcfD8a/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you provide a [mcve] showing at least an example of input and expected output.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I shared the code in the structure of [Google Colab] (https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1vsfukFqOOZZjTajySM8hL0VNCvOxaa6X?usp=sharing)

Comment: This is not a [mcve], try a bit harder.